# How can I have a public Azure AppService app talk to many private Azure AppService Apps?

Tags: azure, vnet

re-asking the following question 3 and 5 years later....
[Private Azure Cloud Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30480600/private-azure-cloud-service)
[Azure Back end app services with no public ip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38404756/azure-back-end-app-services-with-no-public-ip)

I would like to do this with AppService and AzFunctions.

I want to have 1 app exposed to the public.
I want to have several apps private.
I want the public app to have full access to the private apps.

My dream would be that I could Manage Identity my apps the same way I can assign rights for my app to access KeyVault.

Another approach if it could be done, is all my apps on a vnet, but one app also has a public IP.

Is this doable in a nice way yet that isn't kubernetes and just using native azure techniques ;)

Answer (score 1):

By default WebApps have a public IP.

What I have found useful is that I expose my public WebApp as normal but I **add access restrictions to all my internal WebApps/services**.

All WebApps are wrapped into one virtual network.

For internal WebApps, in access restriction tab, access is only allowed through a virtual network, and all other calls are denied.

[image]

Comment: I wish one of these Azure Microsoft MVPs wrote a blog/tutorial about this approach.